# set timer/ set timeout delay in mouseenter function

Tags: jquery, delay, settimeout

For some reason I can't get this to timeout - I want a delay because, at the moment, when a user simply moves the mouse over the element it starts bouncing, and if the user crosses over the button with the mouse three times, the bounce will bounce, you guessed it - three times!

So my idea is to delay the reaction by say 250ms before the bounce function is activated.

Hoverintent blew my mind so I'm trying a settimeout?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
//Hover your mouse pointer over the orange box
$('#myimage').mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).effect('bounce',500);
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Matt

Comment: Just use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: @Dom delay will not work because it will simply delay the animation, if you hover 3 times it will still bounce 3 times

Comment: I thought that was what the OP wanted based on title and content... my apologies.

Comment: OP was not too clear on the issue, but I am pretty sure he wants to implement something like hoverintent so normal travel page hover does not trigger the bounce

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your question correctly, the problem is not with `delay` as the mouseenter is fired already even if user moves mouse over image by mistake it will start  bounce, instead set a flag to check if mouse is on image at least for 500 milliseconds and then fire image bounce effect.

```
 var flag = false;
 $('#myimage').hover(function(){
      flag = true;
      var that = $(this);
      window.setTimeout(function(){
          if(flag) that.effect('bounce', 500);
      }, 300);
 }, function(){
      flag = false;
 });
```

Comment: I voted up your answer because the logic is correct, I did not verify the code though. In my current projection, we set up a timeout so if the mouse is paused (xxx ms) then do your thing, if mouse left clear timeout so it does not fire

Comment: Fantastic, that worked! They don't pay you guys enough! Thanks for your help

Comment: @user2697629 If your problem is resolved, accept the answer which you find matching your requirement.

Comment: They don't pay us at all, which is why accepting the answer is important

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you experience of the element bouncing three times is because the animation queue  builds up on every mouseenter event, you can prevent this by calling `.stop(true,true)` to end the current animation and clear the queue every time the effect starts:

```
$(function(){
     $('#myimage').mouseenter(function() {
         $(this).stop(true,true).effect('bounce',500,function(){
             $(this).css('top',0);
         });
    });
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4SDK/4/)**

Comment: Gave that a shot, for some bizzare reason it makes the buttons stop a little higher than they originally were and eventually they float off the screen entirely if the mouse repeatedly goes over them!

Comment: @user2697629 I updated my answer to include a fix for that issue. Note that the logic for stopping the animation is correct, it's just that this particular bounce effect messes with some positioning properties

Comment: this would still make the button bounce as soon as you hover, the time out way is best so that you don't get a bunch of random bounces as your mouse move around the page or through nav items

Comment: @Huangism I know, it's just a different solution to overcome the undesirable effect which I believe is the fact that the animation queue builds up

Comment: @koala_dev understood as your solution does that :)