# .hover is causing repeated animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was browsing and I saw this site

http://www.toybox.co.nz/

I liked the animation that happens when we hover over the image. Since it works only in chrome I decided to code it.

Below is my code

```
var len,i,hoverindex,flag=0;
  $(function(){
    len = $(".clubsevent").length;
    $(".clubsevent").hoverIntent(function(){
      if(flag==0){
        flag=1;
            hoverindex= $(".clubsevent").index(this);
     $(".clubsevent").eq(hoverindex).css('z-index',2);
     for(i=0;i<len;i++){
      if(i!=hoverindex){
        var rand=Math.random();
        var elemheight =rand*parseInt($(".clubsevent").eq(i).css('height'));
        var elemwidth =rand*parseInt($(".clubsevent").eq(i).css('width'));
        var elemleft = Math.random()*250;
        var elemtop = Math.random()*250;
        var elemopacity = Math.random()*.6;
        $(".clubsevent").eq(i).animate({
          left:elemleft,
          top:elemtop,
          height:elemheight,
          width:elemwidth,
          opacity:elemopacity,
        },250);
      }

     }

      }


    },function(){
         if(flag==1){
           flag=0;
           for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        var elemheight =50;
        var elemwidth =100;
        var elemleft = $(".clubsevent").eq(i).attr('left');
        var elemtop = $(".clubsevent").eq(i).attr('top');
        var elemopacity = 1;
       $(".clubsevent").eq(i).animate({
          left:elemleft,
          top:elemtop,
          height:elemheight,
          width:elemwidth,
          opacity:elemopacity,
       },250);
      }
         }




    });
  })
```

this  is my css part

```
  .clubsevent{
    height:50px;
    width: 100px;
    opacity:1;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #cepheid{
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    background: #6600FF;
  }
  #endeavour{
    top:100px;
    left:210px;
    background: #FF0000;
  }
  #electronika{
    top:100px;
    left:320px;
    background: #6600FF;
  }
  #e-cell{
    top:100px;
    left:430px;
    background: #6600FF;
  }
  #infero{
    top:160px;
    left:100px;
    background: #6600FF;
  }
  #informals{
    top:160px;
    left:210px;
    background: #6600FF;
  }
  #kludge{
    top:160px;
    left:320px;
    background: #6600FF;
  }
  #robotics{
    top:160px;
    left:430px;
    background: #6600FF;
  }
  #torque{
    top:220px;
    left:100px;
    background: #6600FF;
  }
```

this is my html part

```
<div class="clubsevent" left="100" top="100" id="cepheid"></div>
<div class="clubsevent" left="210" top="100" id="endeavour"></div>
<div class="clubsevent" left="320" top="100" id="electronika"></div>
<div class="clubsevent" left="430" top="100" id="e-cell"></div>
<div class="clubsevent" left="100" top="160" id="infero"></div>
<div class="clubsevent" left="210" top="160" id="informals"></div>
<div class="clubsevent" left="320" top="160" id="kludge"></div>
<div class="clubsevent" left="430" top="160" id="robotics"></div>
<div class="clubsevent" left="100" top="220" id="torque"></div>
```

I am able to send all other images to random positions. But the problem is that sometimes when I hover over one element. The animation happens repeatedly.I thought that may be it happens because the other elements which were getting animated were triggering it. I added a flag, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please include your HTML or try recreate the problem in JSFiddle so that it can be debugged properly

Comment: If you're showing an element on hover, and that element ends up going under the mouse, the hoverout event will be triggered immediately because you left the hovered element to go over the animated element. simply an error of logic.

Comment: I have added the HTML and CSS content

Answer (score 1):

```
var len,i,hoverindex,flag=0;
$(function(){
len = $(".clubsevent").length;
$(".clubsevent").hoverIntent(function(){
  if(flag==0){
    flag=1;
        hoverindex= $(".clubsevent").index(this);
 $(".clubsevent").eq(hoverindex).css('z-index',2);
 for(i=0;i<len;i++){
  if(i!=hoverindex){
    var rand=Math.random();
    var elemheight =rand*parseInt($(".clubsevent").eq(i).css('height'));
    var elemwidth =rand*parseInt($(".clubsevent").eq(i).css('width'));
    var elemleft = Math.random()*250;
    var elemtop = Math.random()*250;
    var elemopacity = Math.random()*.6;
    $(".clubsevent").eq(i).animate({
      left:elemleft,
      top:elemtop,
      height:elemheight,
      width:elemwidth,
      opacity:elemopacity,
    },250);
  }

 }

  }


},function(){
     if(flag==1){
       flag=0;
       for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    var elemheight =50;
    var elemwidth =100;
    var elemleft = $(".clubsevent").eq(i).attr('left');
    var elemtop = $(".clubsevent").eq(i).attr('top');
    var elemopacity = 1;
   $(".clubsevent").eq(i).stop().animate({
      left:elemleft,
      top:elemtop,
      height:elemheight,
      width:elemwidth,
      opacity:elemopacity,
   },250);
  }
     }




});
})
```

I've added .stop() before the animate function:
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: still there is problem

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, refer my answer here for same kind of question [set timer/ set timeout delay in mouseenter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321791/set-timer-set-timeout-delay-in-mouseenter-function/18321920#comment26890465_18321920)

```
 var flag = false;
 $('#ele').hover(function(){
   flag = true;
   var that = $(this);
   window.setTimeout(function(){
      if(flag) that.animate({...}, 500);
   }, 300);
 }, function(){
   flag = false;
 });
```

Comment: For delaying I had used hoverIntent plugin. I tried this also. But still I am having problems